# "В городе Чайковский" или "в городе Чайковском"?

Tags: стили-речи, синтаксис

Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: в городе Чайковский. Если есть слово "город" перед названием, то само название не склоняется. То есть, либо "в городе Чайковский", либо "В Чайковском".

Answer (score 0):

в городе Чайковском, но сочиненно - Чайковским.

Answer (score 0):

В городе Чайковском.